# Swap DOM Elements with Timeout

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

I currently try to get into JavaScript a bit. (vanilla)
So at the moment what i want to do is swap different element nodes.
As an example imagine a list with different entries, which later shall be swapped.

For this for `element.length` times random elements should be swapped. After each of this swaps should be a timeout.

The problem which i now encounter is that the list only updates after the shuffle function finishes.

It is intended to swap a pair, wait for 1 second and then do the next swap.

```
function shuffle(element){
    disableButtons();
    let clicked_elmnt = document.getElementsByTagName(element);
    console.log(clicked_elmnt);
    if(clicked_elmnt.length !== 1 && clicked_elmnt !== 0){
        for (let i = 0; i<clicked_elmnt.length;++i){
            setTimeout(function(){doIt(element,randomNumber(clicked_elmnt.length),randomNumber(clicked_elmnt.length))}, 1000)
        }
    }
    enableButtons();
}
```

This code should check if there is a list in a list and then roll new numbers if it tries to swap a parent with its child. **(Seems to be working)**

```
function doIt(element,first,second){
        let clicked_elmnt = document.getElementsByTagName(element);

        if(clicked_elmnt[first].children.length > 0){
            if(clicked_elmnt[first].firstElementChild.isSameNode(clicked_elmnt[second].parentNode)){
                doIt(element,randomNumber(clicked_elmnt.length),randomNumber(clicked_elmnt.length));
            }else{
                if(clicked_elmnt[second].children.length > 0){
                    if(clicked_elmnt[second].firstElementChild.isSameNode(clicked_elmnt[first].parentNode)){
                        doIt(element,randomNumber(clicked_elmnt.length),randomNumber(clicked_elmnt.length));
                    }else{
                        doSwap(clicked_elmnt[first],clicked_elmnt[second]);
                    }
                }else{
                    doSwap(clicked_elmnt[first],clicked_elmnt[second]);
                }
            }   
        }else{
            if(clicked_elmnt[second].children.length > 0){
                if(clicked_elmnt[second].firstElementChild.isSameNode(clicked_elmnt[first].parentNode)){
                    doIt(element,randomNumber(clicked_elmnt.length),randomNumber(clicked_elmnt.length));
                }else{
                    doSwap(clicked_elmnt[first],clicked_elmnt[second]);
                }
            }else{
                doSwap(clicked_elmnt[first],clicked_elmnt[second]);
            }
        }
    }
```

And the swap then happens in the next function. Here they are swapped.

```
function doSwap(n1, n2){
    console.log("swap");
    const afterN2 = n2.nextElementSibling;
    const parent = n2.parentNode;
    if (n1 === afterN2) {
        parent.insertBefore(n1, n2);
      } else {
        n1.replaceWith(n2);
        parent.insertBefore(n1, afterN2);
      }   
}
```

Hope someone can help me here without that much weird stuff.
Cheers!

Comment: Please produce a [example]. Your description is confusing as you say "_After each of this swaps should be a timeout._" yet your timeout happens and then you call `doSwap()`. That is opposite of what you describe. As for the `shuffle()` function finishing early, that's the way asynchronous code works. The timeouts will _eventually_ occur (perhaps 1 sec later), but that is long after the rest of the code has finished executing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is you wish that the `doIt` calls, the callbacks of `setTimeout` to be 1 second apart from each other. The way `setTimeout` works is the callbacks are queued to be executed x milliseconds after `setTimeout` is called. If you want one function to be called 1 second after the previous function finishes, you could call another `setTimeout` from inside the callback.

Here's your example adjusted as such - the `doItLater` function includes a setTimeout call, and will recursively call itself `clicked_elmnt.length` times. You may be able to set it up more cleanly for a real scenario, but this fits without deviating too much from your example.

```
function shuffle(element) {
  disableButtons();
  let clicked_elmnt = document.getElementsByTagName(element);
  if (clicked_elmnt.length !== 1 && clicked_elmnt !== 0) {
    const doItLater = function (i) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        doIt(element, randomNumber(clicked_elmnt.length), randomNumber(clicked_elmnt.length));
        
        if (i + 1 < clicked_elmnt.length) {
          doItLater(i + 1);
        }
      }, 1000);
    }
    doItLater(0);
  }
  enableButtons();
}
```

If you want to only call `enableButtons` after the last `doIt` call finishes, you could move that call to the `else` clause of `if (i + 1 < clicked_elmnt.length)`.